# 'boost/mpl/identity.hpp' file not found

Tags: boost

Not Found: 'boost/mpl/identity.hpp'
Typically, the compiler's error message that reads "'boost/mpl/identity.hpp' file not found" means that it was unable to locate the given header file in the Boost library.

I verified the installation of Homebrew and set the header search paths to /usr/local/include and /usr/local/lib, but the issue persisted. why?

Comment: Because the header can not be found through the search paths. This is a hard fact. Trace the problem from there. Clearly /usr/local/include/boost/mpl/identity.hpp doesn't exist. Have you checked (you don't actually need to, but have you?)